# Parse Through Json Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

This the json file, I want to access the token ID and write it to a file , I try this method but it fails:

python:

```
data=json.loads(content.getvalue())
result=json.dumps(data, indent=4, separators = (', ', ': '))



f=open("/home/moby/writing.txt","w")
f.write(result.access.token.id)


f.close()
```

json:

```
{
    "access": {
        "token": {
            "issued_at": "2013-12-19T05:16:05.901222", 
            "expires": "2013-12-20T05:16:05Z", 
            "id": "d08249e885b24d248f7935a1aa528e28", 
            "tenant": {
                "enabled": true, 
                "description": null, 
                "name": "admin", 
                "id": "de30c00c1a8a488999bfb557f8748222"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "fail" mean?  Is there an error message?  If so, *please* copy and paste it into the question as an edit.

Comment: If there is no error, you will have to be specific on why you say it is failing.  Think of it like this... if you go to the doctor, you wouldn't just say "I hurt" and expect a diagnosis.  Same thing with asking for help with debugging.

Comment: Folks, it's not hard to see why the code is not working.

Comment: @qwrrty: For Python programmers, sure. But it's still good form to include any relevant tracebacks.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - agreed, it's always good form to be explicit about it! But on the flip side, when someone asks why their code isn't working, it's good form not to ignore the obvious reasons. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Um...

```
with open("/home/moby/writing.txt","w") as f:
  f.write(data[u'access'][u'token'][u'id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads` produces a dictionary, and that's not how you use a dictionary.

Get the data you need by using the keys:

```
.write(data[u'result'][u'access'][u'token'][u'id'])
```